# The updated instructions on the master branch might be incorrect

Tags: corda

[API reference: Kotlin/ JavaDoc](https://docs.corda.net/head/getting-set-up.html#run-from-intellij)

In the steps:

> 7 Wait until the run windows displays the message Webserver started up in XX.X 
>      sec
>
> 8 Test the CorDapp is running correctly by visiting the front end at 
>      `http://localhost:10007/web/example/

`"Webservers started up in xx.x sec"` only show for ports: 10012, 10009, and 10015

http://localhost:10012/web/example works, and same for 10009 and 10015
  http://localhost:10012 works, and same for 10009 and 10015

Port 10007 just sits there and waits.

I have no build errors and all the other functionality working as expected.

Is this what I am supposed to see, and documentation is not correct? Or have I somehow messed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect. Thank you for flagging this.

The nodes have been modified to start their webservers on ports 10009, 10012 and 10015. See https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/build.gradle.

This is being fixed in this PR: https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3298.